# Symfony2 logging with items best approach

Tags: symfony, logging

I have a site with multiple items, eg. products in a shop. I want to set up a logger that lets me do two things:

- Log messages related to each product. Thus I want to provide product's id with every log message.
- In admin area view logs for single product, not all log history.

I would construct a entity that enables me to store logs with second parameter:

```
$logger->info("message", $productId);
```

Then store that in database and later select by product id.

But we have monolog and lots of other logging bundles. Is there any better approach than to construct my own entity for storing logs like this?

Answer (score 1):

You should think whats gonna be your database after a year where you will have a very big data of logs and just a simple database query could take a lot of time, I think logs should be written in files, and i have said files because you should for example make a log file for each day, which will make it more easer to extract this data. And to explore this data if you want to create an entity for your log you can do it and in your log files you can store theme using JSON or CSV formats

Comment: You are right, after some time database will grow. I plan to implement some deleting old entries within a entity since I need only last 20-30 of them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use logstash or full stack ELk( Elasticksearch, Logstash, Kebana), as advanced tool for log analyze http://logstash.net/